# Accessibility for highcharts having multiple series

Tags: highcharts, accessibility, narrator

```js
 
 Highcharts.chart('container',{

            chart: {
                //renderTo: document.getElementById("container"),
                type: 'column'
            },
                        accessibility: {
                description:'access description'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'this is the graph'
            },
               xAxis: {
                categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
       

    },
    {
        name: 'japan',
        data: [29.9, 73.5, 106.4, 45.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/themes/high-contrast-light.js"></script>

<div id="container" tabindex="0" style="padding: 10px 1px 1px 1px; height: 240px; width: 500px;"></div>
```

I have a column chart with two series. The narrator creates issue in reading the data in such scenario whereas with one series, it's working. Any insights on this?

Demo project: jsfiddle.net/pfsbyxwz/3

Comment: Configuration options here, have you made sure to caption all items separately? Looks like there's only one description in your code. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module. Accessible demos here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo#accessible-charts

Comment: Hey @NathanielFlick
I added separate descriptions as well. Can you please guide me on what tags are required to enable accessibility for multiple columns.
Also, what is the key combination required to read the data (I am using Chrome - with inbuilt narrator using Ctr+Win+Enter) . As of now, using, Tab plus arrow keys combination.

Comment: Hey, check out this post here, has some more detailed information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408398/highcharts-svg-accessibility?rq=1

Comment: Are you able to navigate between points without using the scan mode, but just using the tab and the left/right arrows? Like I did in this video: https://hnet.com/video-to-gif/viewimage/20210304-23-tFtIDiZ6zMmHLVLS-N80LhG-HNET